# How to read a plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, plist

I'm new to `objective C` and i want to read a plist and than say if the string has this value do this and this.

I've tried this:

```
NSString *filePath = @"E/eg.plist";  
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                                  initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *value;value = [plistDict 
objectForKey:@"lang"];
if (NSString *value = @"1") {
     mySwitch3.on = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you get the value for the given key and compare it to another string.

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *value = [plistDict objectForKey:@"lang"];
if ([value isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    mySwitch3.on = YES;
}
```

For more on Objective-C: [Learning Objective-C A Primer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/)

And Plist programming: [PropertyLists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)